# deluge autoadd plugin isn't working for me

Tags: deluge

I'm running Ubuntu server and I have deluge installed. When I try to enable the autoadd plugin from the webui nothing happens. Does anybody know why this happens any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no WebUI preferences page for that plugin. There is a list of [Deluge Plugins](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Plugins) with details of which have a WebUI preferences page.

It is on the [todo list](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/ticket/2179) but in the meantime you can use a [Thinclient setup](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) to enable and modify the plugin from GTK UI.